# Is AES Encryption different from language to language?

Tags: java, vb.net, encryption

Recently I have some files which are piped from a remote connection as encrypted files and loaded onto an Android app which are decrypted on runtime. I have found that the exact same decryption code is available here along with the keys. Unfortunately it is in Java and hence one that I am not familiar with, I have no experience with encryption. The link for the module is here

https://github.com/fukata/AES-256-CBC-Example/blob/master/java/src/AESUtil.java

The encrypted example is here
https://zerobin.net/?c5fd41740c9301ef#iNG7oNExRZwK4hBEKP7ZORDBj1fcPZxyjLQZeAihGZ8=

I have been trying to decrypt it by using AES utilities found in VB.NET but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. So my question is are AES encryption methods different from language to language? IE is something encoded by AES in Java different from one in VB.NET - which would mean i would have to translate the java code directly?

Thanks!

Comment: AES is an encryption algorithm. An algorithm is a set of steps to achieve a result. Either an algorithm is implemented or it's not. How it's implemented is irrelevant. Each language will implement each step in an algorithm using whatever tools are available in that language and then produce the result. In short, each language must, by necessity, provide it's own implementation of an encryption algorithm but also, by necessity, produce the same result. The only way for two languages to produce different results would be for one or both of them to not actually implement the algorithm.

Comment: @jmcilhinney You should post this as an answer.

Comment: "...but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work...". So show your VB code and be specific about how "it doesn't work". Show the inputs and outputs, and any error messages in full detail, and the experts here will have the answer in no time at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the bit-for-bit identical key and initialization vector as well as the same block chaining mode, but other than that, the language in which an encryption algorithm is written does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

"Is AES Encryption different from language to language?" no.

aes is only an algorithm (computation instruction). aes has maybe a reference-implementation, but it has no "one only correct standardized implementation".

the implementation of aes may be a little bit different in any language. for example in vb.net you would typically use "Byte" as type for an unsigned number in an aes-implementation. however java has no unsigned datatypes, so you have to convert the bytes which are representing negative numbers to avoid encoding-problems. but you do not change the real encryption-algorithm. so you can encrypt your data with an aes-implementation in an arbitrary language and decrypt it with an aes-implementation which is written in another language. if this does not work one of the implementations is flawed.